# Is there any efficient and optimized way to store 500M+ elements in long[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, memory

In my exam's first question : I am working on a small task where I am required to store around 500Million+ elements in an Array.

However, I am running into a heap space problem. Could you please help me with this to best optimal storage algorithm ?

I found "BitSet" but I dont know how to use it.

Step 1 - Create 3 long[] arrays with very large length (Least 100M+)

Step 2 - Init values should be randomly generated, not sorted, may contain duplicates

Step 3 - Merge them after init with randomly (3 long[] arrays)

Step 4 - Duplicate items should be removed in output

I wrote a few things :

```
package exam1;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Furkan
 */

//VM OPTIONS -> -Xincgc -Xmx4g -Xms4g

public final class Exam1 {

private static final int LENGTH = 100000000;

private volatile long[] m_testArr1 = null;
private volatile long[] m_testArr2 = null;
private volatile long[] m_testArr3 = null;

private volatile long[] m_merged = null;

private Random m_r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exam1 exam = new Exam1();

    Instant start1 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Fill Started");
    exam.Fill();

    Instant end1 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Fill Ended : " + Duration.between(start1, end1)); 

    Instant start2 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Merge Started");
    exam.Merge();
    Instant end2 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Merge Ended : " + Duration.between(start1, end1)); 

    Instant start3 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("DupRemove Started");
    exam.DupRemove();
    Instant end3 = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("DupRemove Ended : " + Duration.between(start1, end1)); 
}

private void Fill(){
    this.m_testArr1 = new long[Exam1.LENGTH];
    this.m_testArr2 = new long[Exam1.LENGTH];
    this.m_testArr3 = new long[Exam1.LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < Exam1.LENGTH; i++) {
        this.m_testArr1[i] = this.m_r.nextLong();
        this.m_testArr2[i] = this.m_r.nextLong();
        this.m_testArr3[i] = this.m_r.nextLong();
    }
}

private void Merge(){
    this.m_merged = this.TryMerge(this.m_testArr1, this.m_testArr2, this.m_testArr3);
}

 private void DupRemove(){
    this.m_merged = this.RemoveDuplicates(this.m_merged);
}

public long[] TryMerge(long[] arr1, long[] arr2, long[] arr3){
    int aLen = arr1.length;
    int bLen = arr2.length;
    int cLen = arr3.length;

    int len = aLen + bLen + cLen;

    //TODO: Use BitSize for RAM optimize. IDK how to use...

    //OutOfMemory Exception on this line. 
    long[] mergedArr = new long[len];
    this.m_merged = new long[len];

    //long[] mergedArr = (long[]) Array.newInstance(long.class, aLen+bLen+cLen);

    System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, mergedArr, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, mergedArr, aLen, bLen);
    System.arraycopy(arr3, 0, mergedArr, (aLen + bLen), cLen);


    return mergedArr;
}

//!!!NOT WORKING!!!
private long[] RemoveDuplicates(long[] arr){
    HashSet<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();

    final int len = arr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }

    long[] clean = new long[set.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterator<Long> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        clean[i++] = it.next();
    }
    return clean;
}
}
```

## UPDATE

Original Question ;

-Implement an efficient methot to merge 3 sets of very large (Length: 100M+) long[] arrays.

-Input data randomly generated, not sorted, may contain duplicateds

-Duplicate items should be removed in output.

(8 GB RAM i have)

Run Args: -Xincgc -Xmx4g -Xms4g

Exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at test.

Comment: Do you need all 500+ in memory same time?

Comment: Why don't you create a HashSet only? Don't see why you need the array. While generating the values duplicates will be discarded immediately. No need for a seperate method. Like you do it you will have the array and the set in memory at the same time.

Comment: AFAIK the run arg -Xincgc is deprecated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919213/is-xxuseg1gc-the-correct-replacement-for-xincgc

Comment: I added original question. Searching the best way to do this. I found BitSet but I dont know how to use this. Is this solve this question ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Answer (score 3):

Since you have limited space, and assuming you're allowed to modify the 3 random arrays, I'd suggest the following.

1. For each of the 3 arrays:

   1. Sort the array, e.g. using `Arrays.sort()`.
   2. Eliminate duplicates by compacting non-repeating numbers to the beginning.
      E.g. if you have `{1,2,2,3,3}`, you compact to `{1,2,3,?,?}` with length 3, where `?` means value don't matter.
   3. *(optional)* Move to array of correct size, and discard original array, to free up space for result array(s).
2. Create result array of size `len1 + len2 + len3`.
3. Merge the 3 arrays to the result, eliminating duplicates between the arrays.
   E.g. if you have `{1,3,5}`, `{1,2,3}`, you end up with `{1,2,3,5,?,?}` with length 4.
4. If needed, copy result to new array of correct size.
   If low on memory, release 3 original arrays before doing this to free up space.

Comment: Sort not allowed on this question. Only merge and duplicate ways allowed. I updated the question end of the my question. Thank you for response.

Comment: I don't see where in the question it says that sorting is not allowed, but heck it's your assignment, not mine.

Comment: What happens if all the values are different from each other? In this case there will be no reduction in the array size. (100M *3 = 300M) I'm getting an error when I'm already generating a new array with (len1+len2+len3) As a result, not a solution to this problem, but this is a good way in less elementary arrays.

Comment: If your assignment is to create 3 `long[]` arrays of (at least) 100 million entries, and a result array of 300 millions entries, and you don't have enough memory for that, then the assignment is unsolvable. A `long` is 8 bytes, to `100M + 100M + 100M + 300M = 600M entries * 8 bytes = 4800 MB` which exceeds the `-Xmx4g` defined memory limit. It simply cannot be done with 4 GB if there are no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, when I change ram limit to 6GB, Its working successfully. But I think its not efficient and optmized if each array item is unique. How can I improve this code? Will 'BitSet' fix this? If yes, How do i implemet it ?

Comment: [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) would need to cover full range of `long`, i.e. up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. You don't have 1 [**exabyte**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) of memory, do you? Doesn't matter, since `BitSet` only supports `int` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to identify possible duplicates, then use a hash set to weed out the false positives from the set of possible duplicates, i.e.

foreach source array element, add it to the Bloom filter; if the element is (possibly) contained in the bloom filter, then add it to a hash set, else add it to the merged array.  When all source arrays are processed, check each element of the merged array to see if it is in the hash set, removing duplicates from the hash set.  Finally, add all remaining elements of the hash set to the merged array.

[Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html) has a bloom filter data structure that you can use.

Comment: It seems to be a difficult thing. Are there any example for this ? I would be very pleased, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough memory to store all the data you need to change something by analysing the business requirements and the real world situation.

Maybe you should use some built in collection framework as others suggested.

Or if it is not allowed (for whatever reason) you should save the data somewhere else than memory. E.g.

- sort the arrays
- watch the three array with three moving indexes (i, j, k)
- always pick the smallest of arr1[i], arr2[j], arr3[k]
- ignore if it is a duplicate and move on
- write to a file if it is a new value
- and increment the corresponding index
- do it until the end of each array

Now you have the sorted duplicate free merged array in a file which you can read if necessary after dropping the originals.