# Java GC log with extrem real time values

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have the following GC log which shows timings which can't be quite right:

```
2017-10-01T11:42:19.115+0200: 158277.307: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-10-01T11:42:19.115+0200: 158277.307: [ParNew: 83271K->1819K(92160K), 0.0267320 secs] 285034K->203588K(296960K) icms_dc=0 , 0.0269819 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-10-01T11:42:34.459+0200: 158292.637: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-10-01T11:42:34.459+0200: 158292.637: [ParNew: 83739K->1778K(92160K), 0.0046469 secs] 285508K->203547K(296960K) icms_dc=0 , 0.0049024 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-10-01T11:42:45.053+0200: 158303.240: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-10-01T11:42:45.053+0200: 158303.240: [ParNew: 83698K->1475K(92160K), 0.0257372 secs] 285467K->204066K(296960K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0259963 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-10-01T11:42:51.273+0200: 158309.457: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.279/52268.162 secs] [Times: user=4273.98 sys=2016.78, real=52269.51 secs] 
2017-10-01T11:42:51.288+0200: 158309.466: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-01T11:42:51.288+0200: 158309.471: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.006/0.006 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-10-01T11:42:51.288+0200: 158309.472: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-01T11:42:58.819+0200: 158317.005: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-10-01T11:42:58.819+0200: 158317.005: [ParNew: 83395K->978K(92160K), 0.0035692 secs] 285986K->203570K(296960K) icms_dc=12 , 0.0037514 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2017-10-01T11:43:05.116+0200: 158323.306: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.359/13.834 secs] [Times: user=1.45 sys=0.61, real=13.83 secs]
```

Note especially the times in the fourth line `[Times: user=4273.98 sys=2016.78, real=52269.51 secs]`. That would indicate a GC pause of ~14 hours!?! The system runs Java 8 on Windows virtualized on an ESXI with NTP timing enabled.

EDIT 1: I have more-or-less reproduced the issue on a laptop in the office. Running Windows 10 on bare hardware, Oracle JDK 1.8u121 the following 8.7 and 37.9 second real time are not really explainable for me:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
Memory: 4k page, physical 8312128k(5673796k free), swap 9622848k(6661268k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:CompileThreshold=1500 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=268435456 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2127904768 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456 -XX:MaxNewSize=348966912 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=6 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParNewGC 
2017-10-04T12:43:25.289+0200: 9.804: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-04T12:43:33.995+0200: 18.501: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.033/8.698 secs] [Times: user=0.80 sys=0.08, real=8.71 secs] 
2017-10-04T12:43:33.995+0200: 18.501: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-04T12:43:33.995+0200: 18.503: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-10-04T12:43:33.995+0200: 18.503: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-04T12:43:57.870+0200: 42.375: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-10-04T12:43:57.870+0200: 42.375: [ParNew: 78655K->5667K(78656K), 0.0123267 secs] 117528K->48405K(253440K) icms_dc=5 , 0.0124366 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2017-10-04T12:44:11.909+0200: 56.413: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.398/37.910 secs] [Times: user=0.86 sys=0.09, real=37.91 secs]
```

The system is using around 25% CPU, and ~3.5GB RAM out of 8GB. I [read up](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/understanding-cms-gc-logs) how to read these GC logfiles and `CMS-concurrent-mark-start` to `CMS-concurrent-mark` seems to be a time when threads that have been stopped are restarted. We run around 1000 threads in the application at this time. Is restarting the threads counted towards the real time and not user/sys?

EDIT 2: On the same laptop I disabled the pagefile alltogether and still got high real values.

```
2017-10-04T17:12:47.593+0200: 21.755: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.036/5.195 secs] [Times: user=1.73 sys=0.09, real=5.20 secs]
```

Also had perfmon running and watched "Page Faults / sec", "Page Output /sec" which according to [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938588.aspx) should give me an info about hard page faults which are the ones loading data from the disk. "Page Output / sec" was at 0, so no hard paging. What else could be the issue!? Threads are still a suspect....

Comment: At which time you have a `CMS-initial-mark` in the log?

Comment: `2017-09-30T21:11:41.766+0200: 106041.295: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]` is first instance before the log. Which fits the timing...

Comment: swap, throttling of your VM or massive oversubscription of your system's CPU resources would be prime suspects here.

Comment: You might need to have a look at your JVM memory settings. At `11:42:19`, `11:42:34` and `11:42:45` objects (around 80 MB) from the young generation where collected and gc'ed. Use for example jconsole to monitor the gc cycles and the memory consumption.

Comment: @the8472 swap was also the primary suspect, but since it could be reproduced on a barebone machine with plenty of RAM...!? Also happening really early at 18 seconds into the run....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CommandLine flags: -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode [...]

You're using incremental mode. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33919430/1362755), it is [deprecated](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/173) and was only ever meant for single-core CPUs, it doesn't make sense to use it. Incremental mode gives up time slices from the collector to application threads, thus making the concurrent collection phase take much more wall time (but not necessarily CPU time) compared to non-incremental mode.

Comment: Removing the incremental mode improved the GC situtation on machines where swapping was not the cause of the long pauses!