# Eclipse Unrecognized option: -Xincgc

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently running Eclipse on Windows and received an error message I could not decipher:

```
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc
```

I have not found any other case of a similar error and could need some help.
I am not sure if I am missing a tool or JRE / JDK.

Comment: Welcome Grifting!  I just reviewed about a dozen first posts and yours is excellent.  That said, it is a possible/partial/near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919213/is-xxuseg1gc-the-correct-replacement-for-xincgc where you might find some better answers than mine.

Comment: I'm guessing you posted because you can't google anything starting with a minus sign (minus means 'exclude' so if you search for `cats -dogs` you only find pages with the word cats and without the word dogs).  Put quotes around it instead: "-Xincgc" and you should find your answer.

Comment: that may explain the few google entries..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Xincgc was an old JVM option that meant, "Use Incremental Garbage Collection."  I think it has been deprecated or removed from newer versions of Java.  You can probably just delete it.  It might be in your Maven .pom file or your Gradle file, or in the build options in Eclipse.