# How can I fix the "Unrecognized option -Xincgc "

Tags: java, minecraft

I've tried everything, and I still getting this problem when I run MCP.

> Unrecognized option -Xincgc

I really would like anyone who could help. I know this is for older versions of Java, so all I need is the file location where I can remove it. I want to see how Minecraft works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is -XX:+UseG1GC the correct replacement for -Xincgc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919213/is-xxuseg1gc-the-correct-replacement-for-xincgc)

Comment: This flag is for tweaking GC performance so you should be able to safely remove it without experiencing any issues. This is a command line argument for adjusting how the JVM runs so there is no file associated with it.

Comment: ill try
thanks <3

Comment: @Locke So how can i remove the command line?

Comment: How are you running this Java application? From the Minecraft launcher? If so, go to Installations -> (select the version you want to edit) -> Edit -> More Options. Then you can delete `-Xincgc` from the JVM Arguments section.

Comment: I am using MCP so I'm running it from Eclipse

Comment: How is eclipse configured to run it? It may be using some form of `maven run` or `gradlew.bat run`, which would mean you can modify your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to remove this command line.

Answer (score 0):

The "mcp918" depends on which **version** of the Mod Coder Pack(*MCP*) you use

**mcp940.zip    = Minecraft client 1.12 & server 1.12**

**mcp937.zip    = Minecraft client 1.11.2 & server 1.11.2**

**mcp931.zip    = Minecraft client 1.10 & server 1.10**

**mcp928.zip    = Minecraft client 1.9.4 & server 1.9.4**

**mcp918.zip    = Minecraft client 1.8.8 & server 1.8.8**

**mcp908.zip    = Minecraft client 1.7.10 & server 1.7.10**

Go to the file location wherever you downloaded Mod Coder Pack (*MCP*)
and then follow this address"mcp918\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches" then open :-

> Client.Launch

with **notepad** or the **IDE** you prefer, remove the line that your error comes from, in this case *-Xincgc* :-

`<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M"/>`

Even if you follow the steps, the game wont be able to run, due to errors that exist within the game's code, if you are able to fix these errors, you can run Mod Coder Pack(***MCP***)